How to check if a SignalR Active Connection is still active or not within .Net8 Isolated SignalRTrigger Azure Function App
Earlier we were using InProcess and hence we had a refrence of InvocationContext which was working fine to check if the signalR connection is active or not to perform our own business logic. The same snippet follows below.
if (await invocationContext.GetClientManager().ConnectionExistsAsync(invocationContext.ConnectionId))
{
   //Code Logic
}

But now we are migrating to .Net 8 Isolated worker hence we can see the SignalRTrigger has changed from "InvocationContext" to "SignalRInvocationContext" model for worker nuget refrence.
But we can't see a similar refrence in SignalRInvocationContext to check if the connection is still existing or not. Can some one provide an equivalent implementation for this.
